# Sequential EEPROM writing

Tags: stm32, i2c, eeprom

I am using an [M24C64 EEPROM](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/5c/df/52/a5/15/f2/48/bd/CD00259166.pdf/files/CD00259166.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00259166.pdf) with an STM32F4, but I have a problem with sequential writing. When I try to write 16-bit data sequentially like this, I get HAL_I2C_ERROR_AF error:

```
write_eeprom(address1,data1);
write_eeprom(address2,data2);
```

But if I put a 5 ms delay between write operations, I could write successfully.

How can I write faster to the EEPROM?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some sort of delay is required because the device is busy writing the data.

The datasheet for this device gives you two options to minimize it:

- page writes (section 5.1.2) to write 32 bytes at a time
- polling instead of using a fixed, worst-case delay of 5ms (section 5.1.6)

If you do page writes, be careful that your addresses are aligned with page boundaries, otherwise the device will silently corrupt the data.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations, if I use the page write, When I read do I have to page read?

Comment: You can use any method to read the data, it doesn't remember _how_ it was written. The different methods are all explained in the datasheet.

Answer (score 6):

You can't write single bytes any faster. Each write operation to a page takes up to 5ms to complete.

However, what you can do is to write multiple bytes into a page, as the chip has a page size of 32 bytes.

So each write of up to 32 bytes within a page takes up to 5ms.